# JSON Deserialization of Cast object returns Uncast JSON

Tags: json, json.net

I'm currently doing some work on an API where I'm Casting an object before serializing it and returning the JSON. I expected the JSON result to be that of the Cast object and not the Uncast object, however I get all the properties in my JSON from the Uncast object

Example code

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JSONSerializationOfCastObject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B InstanceB = new B(){PropA = "A",PropB = "B"};

            A InstanceA = InstanceB;

            var JSONInstanceA = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(InstanceA);

            Console.WriteLine(JSONInstanceA);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public string PropA { get; set; }
    }

    public class B:A
    {
        public string PropB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Result

```
{"PropB":"B","PropA":"A"}
```

Expected result

```
{"PropA":"A"}
```

Another example where the type just isn't what you expect

```
        B InstanceB = new B(){PropA = "A",PropB = "B"};
        A InstanceA = InstanceB;

        var x = InstanceA.GetType() == typeof(A); //==> False but we casted it to A
```

I just cannot figure this out, NewtonSoft must do some reflection under the hood.

GitHub Example here: https://github.com/tharris29/JSONSerializationOfCastObject/tree/master

**update**
So I understand this is to do with reflection but just seems an odd result. Is there a way to tell the serializer what object type to use for serialization?

Comment: That looks correct to me, what issue are you seeing?

Comment: I'm serializing instanceA which only has a property of "propA" I wouldn't have expected the serialiser to know about the "propB".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you have assigned a `B` to an `A` does not mean that it is no longer a `B`.  You can see this for yourself if you print out the type of your `InstanceA` variable after the assignment:

```
B instanceB = new B() { PropA = "A", PropB = "B" };

A instanceA = instanceB;

Console.WriteLine(instanceA.GetType().Name);
```

As you will see, the result is `B`.

Json.Net uses reflection to look at the actual type of an object and get all of its properties.  As far as I know, it does not have a built-in way to limit the properties to just those of a base type.  If you want to do that, you will need a custom `JsonConverter`.  Here is one that might work for you (notice it also uses reflection):

```
public class BaseTypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        T instance = (T)value;
        JObject obj = new JObject();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.CanRead)
            {
                obj.Add(prop.Name, JToken.FromObject(prop.GetValue(instance)));
            }
        }
        obj.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You can use this converter like this:

```
B instanceB = new B() { PropA = "A", PropB = "B" };

// serialize B, but only include the properties from type A
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instanceB, new BaseTypeConverter<A>());

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{"PropA":"A"}
```

Comment: Cheers Brian, yes after a bit of playing I realised that the type was still the same under the hood. I started to play with the JsonConvert also, but your solution is pretty tidy. Thanks for your time.